# Get Selected TextView Text

Tags: textview, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I think I'm not quite understanding something, and hope someone can point me in the right direction....

Within an Angular/Typescript based NativeScript app (not a web app), I'm trying to figure out how I can get the selected text of a TextView element?

I have this in my html:

```
<TextView #testTextView></TextView>
```

And can do this in my component:

```
import { TextView } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/text-view';
@ViewChild('testTextView', { static: false }) textViewRef: ElementRef;

    onTest() {
        let textView: TextView;
        textView = this.textViewRef.nativeElement;
        console.log(textView.text);
      }
```

Which gives me the current text from the field. But I can't figure out how to get the text that may be currently selected by the user. Anyone able to point me in the right direction of how to get the selected text?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no out of the box method to do this. You will have to implement this natively, on Android you could call [getSelectionStart() / getSelectionEnd()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection#getSelectionStart(java.lang.CharSequence)) methods on native view to get start / end index of selection. Similarly on iOS use [selectedTextRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614541-selectedtextrange?language=objc).

Comment: Thanks! That pointed me in the right direction. I ended up installing "tns-platform-declarations" and setting up a "reference.d.ts" file. Once I was able to get intelisense going for native APIs I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close out this post... I followed the breadcrumbs from Manoj and implemented some native calls to get what I wanted. Of course, adding the stuff to get VSCode to give me intelisense on native APIs helped a ton!